# Wiring CO2 sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor, wiring

I have this carbon dioxide (\$CO_2\$) sensor:

[image]

[image]

http://wiring.org.co/learning/basics/airqualitymq135.html

My question is simple...
this sensor has left and right section. But what is left and what is right?
Is there a way to identify parts?

Comment: Can we have a datasheet for the part? Not just a reference to the tutorial you got the images from please.

Comment: Uhm... I don't have link for datasheet...

Comment: @Paska: You should do a little effort! Googling for "MQ135 datasheet" results in [this document](http://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/Sensor/MQ-135.pdf) as the first hit.

Comment: \$CO_2\$ is _NOT_ Carbon Monoxide!  \$CO_2\$ is Carbon Dioxide - which is it?

Comment: @Matt - datasheet mentions \$CO_2\$ but not \$CO\$. fixed in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding this [datasheet](http://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/Sensor/MQ-135.pdf) online it says that A and B can be swapped and that H are the middle pins so that it can be in any orientation just make sure that H are the middle pins. 
 Figure 2 is the one i'm referring to:
[image: gas sensor pin out]

Answer (score 0):

Well not going to datasheet, one can say from the image in your question,
Just hold the sensor facing the pins towards your face, the pin assignment is same as per image (left B-H-B, right A-H-A)

and Dean has very simple answer :)

but my answer would help while using other Sensors along with their mechanical drawings

Comment: Apparently there's no "A" and "B" marking, otherwise he wouldn't ask the question. The part is symmetrical, so if you rotate it over 180 degrees the pinning looks the same. You don't answer that.

Comment: yes its symmetrical , i request you first view the manufactures datasheet and tell whether there's A and B Marking on sensor or not,

Comment: dont jus rule out other's work who have done some reaserch and spent time..

Comment: Even all IC's (Integrated Circuits) the DIP one's have symmetrical physical pin arrangement, that doesn't mean you start pin1 from either of all four possibilities.

Comment: If there was not actual A & B ,he would n't have actually stated A,B in his Question :P

Comment: The difference with DIP ICs is that they have **a clear marking** which side is pin 1. I've never heard anybody having trouble with the symmetry. This device doesn't have any marking, but without the datasheet the question how to identify A and B is justified.